# Why does this jQuery Mobile form not properly AJAX?

Tags: ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile, safari

I am under the (perhaps mistaken?) impression that you can test jQuery Mobile applications during development using Safari rather than having to use a mobile device.

When I

- load Safari in Windows,
- change the *User Agent* to *Safari iOS 4.3.3 — iPhone* in the Developer menu,
- hit this URL: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html, and
- click `Submit` on the **Default Ajax form example**

it does not AJAX. Instead it loads a new URL:

```
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample-response.php?shipping=Standard+shipping&submit=submit-value
```

Are my expectations wrong, am I doing it wrong, or is there something wrong with jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything is wrong, I think you're just being fooled by jQuery Mobile.

It may appear as though a whole-page-refresh is occuring but it isn't. If you watch the Network tab in your developer tools you can see the XHR request for the PHP page.

Then jquery Mobile is changing the URL in the address bar with it's pushState plugin: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

In a general sense, yes, you can use a desktop browser for development but be ready for issues when you move to testing on a device. Sometimes you don't get any, but there are some frustrating bugs in the current mobile browsers.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Not sure how I missed that in the docs. In my case, then, I want to disable `pushState` because the page I am AJAXing only contains the page content, not the whole layout (to minimize content that gets downloaded). Otherwise, when the user refreshes the page using the pushState URL, they would see no layout, CSS, etc. I suppose I could detect whether it is an AJAX request or not, and render the layout depending on that...is there a common pattern in this regard?

Comment: If you disable the pushState plugin you'll get hash tag URLs like this: /index.html#/some-folder/index.html. But it should work for you because this will load the regular index page and then jQuery Mobile will detect the hash tag and grab the content via AJAX from that location.